# Connection Reset when trying a POST request using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, jsp, struts, apache-commons-httpclient, connection-reset

I have a value of a string that I get from a service call in my java backend code. When I get the value of a string I want to make a post request and pass the string as a url encoded base 64 string to the endpoint.

The problem is I get a Socket Exception: Connection reset error. I'm using HttpClient 4.5.2 and IBM Websphere (Rational Application Development) More detailed error is:

```
DefaultHttpClient org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect I/O Exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s} -> https://foo.bar:443: Connection reset
```

Java code:

```
public ActionForward executeShowFormView(
            ActionMapping mapping, 
            ActionForm form, 
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
{
  var stringResponse = serviceCall.getStringResponse(); 
  DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serviceCall.getEndpointUrl()); 
  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("response=" + stringResponse, ContentType.APPLICATION_TYPE_URLENCODED); 
  post.setEntity(entity); 
  HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post); 
}
```

What can I do to fix the error?

Comment: Have you tried the same request from postman to the same server

Comment: @vinaychhabra yes. In postman, I get 500 internal server error. However, even though for that endpoint, I thought it might be an issue. I tried to hit google.com with a get request and I still get connection reset even though in another blank project with hitting google.com with get request, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used httpclient post method. I set request header value as

```
post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1").
```

My application was rolled to production and ran successfully for 1 year. On a sudden it stopped working and I received javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset

Fix:

I changed `post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")`

This resolved my issue.